# Google Places API image request URL doesn't return image

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm trying to get place photos using the Google Places API using SDWebImage to load the images asynchronously. However, the images are not loading. I've double checked to see if my photo_reference was incorrect, but it's the same with the JSON data that I am pulling. Below is my code showing how I'm making the request. I've parsed through the JSON data and gotten the photo_reference associated with each place image. Then I put that photo_reference into a URL string, which is placed into an array and called inside the cellForRowAt table view method.

```
if let results = myReadableJSON["results"] as? [JSONStandard]{
   for i in 0..<results.count{

       let item = results[i]
       let names = item["name"] as! String

       placeNames.append(names)
       print("The number of names is: ", placeNames.count)
       print("The name(s) is/are: ", placeNames[i],"\n")

      // GETTING PLACE PHOTOS AND PUTTING THEM INTO imageURL ARRAY

       if let photos = item["photos"] as? [JSONStandard]{
            for j in 0..<photos.count{

            let photo = photos[j] as JSONStandard

             let photoRef = photo["photo_reference"] as! String

             let photoURL = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=34&photoreference=%@&key=AIzaSyD3f-rVhs_dNPnsNRorgMDw-MH23k4WrPw", photoRef) as? String

             imageURL.append(photoURL!)

      }
   }
}
```

Table View method with SDWebImage method

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! exploreListTableViewCell

    cell.venuesLabel.text = placeNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.venuesImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: " card1"))
    cell.venuesImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.venuesImage.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.venuesImage.clipsToBounds = true


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the google doc, the response of a successful Place Photo request will be an image. The type of the image will depend upon the type of the originally submitted photo.

If your request exceeds your available quota, the server will return an HTTP 403 status and display the image that you added in question to indicate that the quota has been exceeded.

1. So check in response you got any error or not.
2. Make sure your API is unabled from Google  console and must be valid.
3. Check your photo ref param is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was able to get past the original issue I was having, but if you could have a look at my updated question with some new code that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your json data

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution to my problem. Apparently, my API key had a restriction on it to be used only with iOS. So, I put no restrictions on it, and it now grabs the images.

Thanks again